# Repeat a substring in a nonconsecutive position

Tags: python, regex

How shall we write a RegEx that captures repeating a substring in a nonconsecutive position?
For example, in `aaabcaaa`, `aaa` repeats  with `bc` in between.

`\1` can only be used in replacement not in the match pattern, right? Can we write `(.*)bc\1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Regex can be `(.+)bc\1`

```
>>> s = "aaabcaaa"
>>> re.search(r'(.+)bc\1',s).group(1)
'aaa'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/caTJtj1ifpipyPbj)

To solve your doubt let me quote from the [Regex HOWto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping)

> Backreferences in a pattern allow you to specify that the contents of an earlier capturing group must also be found at the current location in the string. For example, `\1` will succeed if the exact contents of group 1 can be found at the current position, and fails otherwise.

The official docs also include a program to solve your problem (slightly changed)

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'(\b\w+)bc\1')
>>> p.search(s).group(1)
'aaa'
```

Comment: Indeed it can be, but you should not because this kind of pattern grow in complexity very very fast.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this will capture both consecutive as well as *non* consecutive repetitions. You should use the `+` quantifier. Not `*`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yeah, It even finds a mention in the regex howto that we shouldn't do such stuff. :D Should I write a note to the effect of this?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yep! Sorry, had forgotten

Comment: @Bhargav better, but not good yet: look more closely ... ;) "non-consecutive" implies there is at least 1 char between the two sub-strings.

Comment: `(.+).+\1` seems good to me given the OP use case. But this has been a hard day: maybe I missed something here ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux GOT IT. The OP wants `bc` in the middle. \o/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use \1 in the match. I guess you haven't tried before asking?